# Programatically Removing and Replacing Watermarks in Word

Tags: windows, ms-word, vbscript

I'm trying to do some standardized document manipulation specifically in a Windows environment on Word documents. For frustratingly silly reasons, I'd also like to do this in VBscript or at least language tools available in Vanilla Windows 10 + Office.

As it stands, the documents coming in all have a standardized text Watermark on them, and I'd like to replace that watermark with a new text watermark. From what I've been able to gather, the watermark is some sort of generalized shape object. I've had some fiddly success finding and deleting all shapes, but it's not clear to me if there is a way to inspect each shape and determine if it is the correct shape in VBscript, or to replace the text hiding somewhere within the shape structure to produce a new watermark.

My deletion looks something like the following, where `lDoc` is a document object of document I'm manipulating.

```vb
sub UpdateWatermark(lDoc)
    Dim section
    Dim hdr, hdr_rng, sp, str
    dim cnv
    dim rng

    for each section in lDoc.Sections
        for each hdr in section.Headers
            For each sp in hdr.Shapes
                if InStr(sp.Name, "PowerPlusWaterMarkObject") > 0 Then
                    sp.Delete
                End if
            next
        next
    next

end sub
```

The strange thing with this brute force *deletion* approach is I'm seeing many `PowerPlusWaterMarkObject`s in the header, but only one is the "for real" watermark. I also am not sure how to create a new object and insert it with the same properties as the one I'm deleting. My preference would be to simply find the watermark object and manipulate it directly. Any Guru's out there who could lend me a hand?

Comment: Probably relevant - [Deleting Watermark in Word Document using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42723964)

Comment: One other thing to consider is that not all things that act as Watermarks are `PowerPlusWaterMarkObject`s. Some are simply images either in the header/footer story or behind text. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Troubleshooting_Watermarks

Comment: @user692942 That's essentially the same as my reference implementation to *delete* the watermark, but it neglects the details of how to *modify* or *add* a watermark.

Comment: @siriusfox It also explains how [not all watermarks are the same object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723964/deleting-watermark-in-word-document-using-excel-vba#comment72661084_42723964).